# Refreshing not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I make some calls to an UI component from an other referenced project over an Interface

UI-component:

```
Public Class PleaseWaitWindow
    Implements PleaseWaitInterface

    Sub New(initStateText As String)

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        tbStateDescription.Text = initStateText
        Me.Activate()
    End Sub

    Public Property currentStepText As String Implements PleaseWaitInterface.currentStepText

        Get
            Return tbStateDescription.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            tbStateDescription.Text = value
            tbStateDescription.InvalidateVisual()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub Display() Implements PleaseWaitInterface.Display
        Me.Show()
        Me.Activate()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements PleaseWaitInterface.Dispose
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Public Property maxSteps As Integer Implements PleaseWaitInterface.maxSteps
        Get
            Return pbCurrentProgress.Maximum
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            pbCurrentProgress.Maximum = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub PerformStep() Implements PleaseWaitInterface.PerformStep
        pbCurrentProgress.Value += 1
        pbCurrentProgress.InvalidateVisual()
    End Sub
End Class
```

As long as I make these calls from within the same project everything works

like here:

```
  Private Function startGeneration_normal() As Boolean
            //Do some stuff
                    pw.PerformStep()
                    pw.currentStepText = ("Loading data, no stepping is available.")
            tar.startworking(pw)
            //Do some stuff
  End Function
```

But when I pass the Interfaceobject into the referenced project and try to use it like this:

```
 Public Function startworking(pw As PleaseWaitInterface) As Boolean
    tempExportFileName = "Export" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm")
    //Do some stuff
    pw.currentStepText = ("Current Task: formating XML")
    //Do some more stuff
 End Function
```

the values in the object changes (checked in debugger), but the visuals are not refreshed until the start_generate function returns from the startworking function. When it returns from the function in the referenced project, the values are refreshed, based on the current state.

Why does the UI not refresh while the program executes the stuff in the referenced project?

Comment: You seems to be running that code synchronously in the UI thread, so it gets blocked and won't update anything. You should use an asynchronous mechanism like BackgroundWorker instead.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Clemens, using a background worker did the trick, so
problem:
resolved